# What is this trophy room for?

Tags: nier-automata

While wandering around the library, I came across this room that I hadn't seen before (or at least have no memory of seeing). Is there any significance to this room?

[image: trophy room]

It seems like all of the statues are bosses or characters in the game, but since some are gold and silver, it doesn't seem like these are just from beating each boss. Plus, it's at the end of the game so it'd be impossible not to have beaten all of the bosses at this point.

Comment: The previous NieR titles had the [Trophy Room](http://nier.wikia.com/wiki/Trophy_Room) as well. It doesn't contain information on NeiR:Automata, but I am assuming it is the same room

Comment: @Wondercricket yeah, I just found that. It looks like the entire library is a copy of the library in the original NIER

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing some research, it appears that this is a reference to the original NIER, as the entire library is a replica of Devola and Popola's library from that game. From [this thread](https://steamcommunity.com/app/524220/discussions/0/135512625246690784/):

> The easter egg is that the whole library is from the first NieR. In the exact same room in the first NieR there were trophies as well but they were trophies of the bosses in that game.

This trophy room is another feature of the original NIER, in which trophies representing all of the defeated bosses were displayed. This room is identical, except the bosses displayed are from NieR: Automata, rather than the original NIER. An image of the original NIER's trophy room can be seen on [the wiki page](http://nier.wikia.com/wiki/Trophy_Room):

> [image: original trophy room]